# Error in Integration of NXP PN7150 NFC controller to android

Tags: android, nfc, nxp-microcontroller

Once all the steps mentioned in the Android porting document(https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN11690.pdf) is completed, the test application NfcFactoryTestApp doesn't work properly. NFC option is available in the settings window, but when its turned ON , dmesg shows the following error

```
pn54x_dev_write : i2c_master_send returned -107
i2c-msm-v2 7575000.i2c : NACK: slave not responding, ensure its powered: msgs(n:1 cur:0 tx) bc(rx:0 tx:4) mode:FIFO slv_addr:0x28 MSTR_STS:0x0d1300c8 OPER:0x00000090
```

Definition added in platform tree file is as follows

```
&i2c_8 {
        pn547: pn547@28 {
                compatible = "nxp,pn547";
                reg = <0x28>;
                clock-frequency = <400000>;
                interrupt-parent = <&tlmm>;
                interrupt-gpios = <&tlmm 10 0>;
                enable-gpios = <&tlmm 11 0>;
        };
};
```

Any help will be appreciated.